# Variance and expectation of the stochastic intergal

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Compute the unconditional expected value and variance, and describe, as far
as possible, the distribution of the random variable

$Y_{t} = \int^{t}_{0} W_{s} ds $

with the hint below

$\int^{t}_{0} \tau dW_{\tau} $ = $ tW_{t} - \int^{t}_{0} W_{\tau} d\tau$

$ \int^{t}_{0} \tau dW_{\tau} $ = $ tW_{t} - \int^{t}_{0} W_{\tau} d\tau $
 With this function f($W_t$)= $tW_t$

( by Ito's integral use $df_t = f_t dt + f_w dW_t + f_wt dt $

$df_t = W_t dt + t dW_t + dW_t dt$

And the last variable is equal to zero . Then the intergal of the above is equal to the hint.)
 The expectation I get is 0  and variance of $ \frac{2}{3} t^3 $ 
but have been told it is something different by other people.

Comment: That it is a martingale by using the hint and for the variance you need to use the ito isometry but don't know if  you get a covariance term as i think they are not independent

Comment: A martingale? Actually, it isn't. Start with the expecation: Use Fubini's theorem to conclude $\mathbb{E}(Y_t)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}var \int_0^t W_t dt &= \int_0^t\int_0^t \min(r,s)dr ds\\
&=\frac 13 t^3\\
E \int_0^t W_t dt &= \int_0^t E W_t dt\\
&=0
\end{align}

Now let's use the hint for the variance

\begin{align}var \int_0^t W_t dt &= var \Big(t\int_0^tdW_{\tau}-\int_0^t \tau dW_{\tau}\Big)\\
&=var \Big(t\int_0^tdW_{\tau}\Big)+var \Big(\int_0^t \tau dW_{\tau}\Big)-2cov \Big(t\int_0^tdW_{\tau},\int_0^t \tau dW_{\tau}\Big)\\
&=t^2 \times t + \int_0^t \tau^2 d \tau -2 t \int_0^t \tau d\tau\\
&=\frac13 t^3
\end{align}
Using the hint for the mean:

\begin{align}E \int_0^t W_t dt &= E \Big(t\int_0^tdW_{\tau}-\int_0^t \tau dW_{\tau}\Big)\\
&=E \Big(t\int_0^tdW_{\tau}\Big)-E\Big(\int_0^t \tau dW_{\tau}\Big)\\
&=0+0\\
\end{align}

Comment: how would you do that with the hint? As it has the same time index ?

Comment: see the edit...

Comment: Great ! The covariance bit was messing my calculation, do you recommend a book to fine tune my maths of this field ?  Appreciate your help, for the exercise due !!!

Comment: This is so fun to get a downvote :-)

Comment: take a look at this book http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Stochastic-Calculus-Statistical-Probability/dp/9810235437/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1427912812&sr=1-1&keywords=Elementary+Stochastic+Calculus